# Parametrizar una consuslta SQL en Power BI

Tags: login, condiciones, powerbi

Soy nuevo en el uso de Power BI. En este momento nos encontramos en el proceso de migración de ciertos reportes a esta nueva herramienta. Actualmente trabajamos con JasperSoft, donde puedo hacer uso de parámetros para limitar la cantidad de información que ofrece una consulta SQL. Un ejemplo claro es el uso del parámetro de LogginUser que puedo implementar en las cláusulas **where**. Sin embargo, en Power BI no he podido localizar esta opción (y tampoco he podido encontrar nada en Internet), lo que veo que se hace es descargar toda la información requerida y luego dar visualización de los datos al usuario que ejecuta el reporte.

Existe algo similar en Power BI, o lo único que se puede hacer es usar el Row-Leve Security?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Power Bi te permite escribir la consulta que se ejecutará contra la base de datos. Así puede setear un WHERE dentro de la consulta en caso que siempre se efectúe de la misma manera.

Caso contrario dentro del editor de consulta puedes manipular el seteo de parametros desde el ambiente productivo.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-parameters

En dicha documentación podrás encontrar información al respecto.

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Con PBI se pueden elaborar distintos tipos de consultas en las cuales puedes parametrizar, por ejemplo utilizando un WHERE.

Comment: Mira [answer] sería bueno que mostrarás algún ejemplo de los distintos tipos de consultas a los que haces mención, esto mejoraría muchísimo la calidad de tu respuesta.